# Camera Plugin Issue on Phonegap 3.3

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, camera

I'm trying to use the Full Example given in:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture

I've created a project, added platform Android, added the Camera Plugin,
Then I've copied the example as is into index.html .

Ran it on an Android 4.3 device, I see an error in the Eclipse's console:

01-22 19:48:26.661: E/Web Console(22707): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PictureSourceType' of undefined:19

(Yes onDeviceReady() is fired like it should)

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: It might have to do with the issue explained in the link you provided under the section "Android Quirks". They provide a link to a stackoverflow issue that should help if that is the issue

Comment: Hey, but I'm using a device with Android 4.3, and the project in Eclipse is set to 4.3, no where it's 4.4+

Comment: Sorry, missed that when I read it

Comment: Have u added the camera permission in manifest file ?

Comment: Yes it was added automatically when added the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
```

to:

```
pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
```

Comment: Hey, but navigator.camera.PictureSourceType is undefined, so ofcourse navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.X will too be undefined. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use phongap build you have to add:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.camera" />
```

to your config.xml no need cordova add plugin etc..

Answer (score 0):

From what I've experienced with this camera plugin, sometimes the plugin won't expose the window.camera as is. Instead, try to access it through `window.plugins`, and if that doesn't work either, try using [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/) with which you will be able to get it working faster.

You should also know that there are some bugs in Android which may crash the Android app.